# Scala - Spark - Neo4j - Delete nodes

Tags: scala, apache-spark, neo4j

I have a scala/spark application that interacts with Neo4j.

I'm able to add/update nodes (starting from a Dataset) but I would like to delete all the nodes in advance before starting to insert them.

I would like to submit the following query:

```
MATCH (n) DETACH DELETE n;
```

I tried with this code without success:

```
def removeDbObjects(s: SparkSession) = {
   val emptyDf = s.emptyDataFrame
   emptyDf.write
    .format("org.neo4j.spark.DataSource")
    .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
    .option("query", "MATCH (n) DETACH DELETE n;")
    .save()
}
```

I have no errors but the nodes are not removed.

I'm using

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>neo4j-connector-apache-spark_2.12</artifactId>
  <version>5.0.3_for_spark_3</version>
</dependency>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you `write` from an empty `DataFrame`, nothing happens.

Use a `DataFrame` with a *single* row (and a single column) of arbitrary data, since you want your Cypher query to be executed once only (and do not care about the DataFrame data).